# Adobe Reader problem in running: internal error

Tags: adobe-reader, adobe-acrobat

I just have installed adobe reader using `apt-get install acroread`. but it does not run, and shows this message: `An Internal Error Occured`

Comment: Is there any reason you need acrobat? Ubuntu has evince installed by default so it can read pdfs without acrobat

Comment: I need tag, highlight and write notes on pages. I could not see these facilities in evince.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with file permissions for the acroread program. Specifically, on starting up it tries to create a folder `.adobe` in your home directory. However, due to some reason (perhaps during install) a symlink file of the same name already exists: `.adobe --> /dev/null`. So, the program throws and error and quits, as seen by running it from the terminal:

> $ acroread
>
> Acroread was unable to create the directory .adobe in your
>   home directory. There may be a permission problem with the parent
>   directory.

```
ls -l ~/.adobe
.adobe -> /dev/null
```

So to solve this problem, just remove the symlink with:

```
rm -v ~/.adobe
```

Now try starting acroread, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above did nothing for me; I can delete the .acroread folder and Acrobat creates a new one, still fails with errors. My environment matches this bug report

[https://forums.adobe.com/message/4721987][1]

which points out that Adobe has a bug reading the its own config from an XFS file system larger than 1T. The thread author provides workarounds for bash and tcsh:

```
[bash]

HOME=`/bin/mktemp --directory` acroread



[(t)csh]

(setenv HOME `/bin/mktemp --directory`; acroread)
```

This was the first solution I found that worked for me. Note that this solution isn't perfect, Acrobat treats every launch as the first one, asked you to acknowledge the EULA, etc. The author also provides a shell script to try and work around that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `acroread` on a *XFS* partition with more than 1 TB.

I copied the directory `/home/<homedir>/.adobe` to a  smaller partition and made a symlink `/home/<homedir>/.adobe` on the copied directory.

After that, `acroread` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had an almost identical problem.
The added wrinkle: the /home area was a bind mount from a very large drive.
This meant that acroread would still crash shortly after launching, even if .adobe was a symlink to an area of a smaller drive.
I modified `/bin/acroread` to export the HOME environment variable pointing to a directory per user on a smaller drive, in a location where the user could write.
This could be e.g. `/tmp/acroHome$USER` which would allow write for each user.
There may be a less messy solution, but it did work when I did this and supported user customisations.